# Sonar throws "fail to execute es search request"

Tags: sonarqube

We recently upgraded our sonar instance from 5.0.1 to 5.1.2

We are getting "fail to execute es search request" error popup when we click issues link.

[Error-Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFdqk.png)

```
2015.10.27 12:23:35 ERROR web[o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://sonar.pe.int.thomsonreuters.com/api/issues/search?p=1&ps=50&s=FILE_LINE&asc=true&extra_fields=actions%2Ctransitions%2CassigneeName%2CreporterName%2CactionPlanName&facets=severities%2Cresolutions%2Cresolutions&resolved=false&componentUuids=8858dbaa-94ca-4293-9a81-e432028be3e0
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute ES search request '{"from":0,"size":50,"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"missing":{"field":"resolution"}},{"terms":{"project":["8858dbaa-94ca-4293-9a81-e432028be3e0"]}},{"has_parent":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":{"or":{"filters":[{"term":{"users":"admin"}},{"term":{"groups":"Anyone"}},{"term":{"groups":"sonar-users"}},{"term":{"groups":"sonar-administrators"}}]}},"_cache":true}}}},"parent_type":"authorization"}}]}}}},"sort":[{"project":{"order":"asc","missing":"_first"}},{"filePath":{"order":"asc","missing":"_first"}},{"line":{"order":"asc","missing":"_first"}},{"severityValue":{"order":"desc","missing":"_first"}},{"key":{"order":"asc","missing":"_first"}}],"aggregations":{"severities":{"global":{},"aggregations":{"severities_filter":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"query":{"match_all":{}}},{"missing":{"field":"resolution"}},{"terms":{"project":["8858dbaa-94ca-4293-9a81-e432028be3e0"]}},{"has_parent":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":{"or":{"filters":[{"term":{"users":"admin"}},{"term":{"groups":"Anyone"}},{"term":{"groups":"sonar-users"}},{"term":{"groups":"sonar-administrators"}}]}},"_cache":true}}}},"parent_type":"authorization"}}]}},"aggregations":{"severities":{"terms":{"field":"severity","size":15,"min_doc_count":1,"order":{"_count":"desc"}}},"severities_selected":{"terms":{"field":"severity","include":"INFO|MINOR|MAJOR|CRITICAL|BLOCKER"}}}}}},"resolutions":{"global":{},"aggregations":{"resolutions_filter":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"query":{"match_all":{}}},{"terms":{"project":["8858dbaa-94ca-4293-9a81-e432028be3e0"]}},{"has_parent":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":{"or":{"filters":[{"term":{"users":"admin"}},{"term":{"groups":"Anyone"}},{"term":{"groups":"sonar-users"}},{"term":{"groups":"sonar-administrators"}}]}},"_cache":true}}}},"parent_type":"authorization"}}]}},"aggregations":{"resolutions":{"terms":{"field":"resolution","size":15,"min_doc_count":1,"order":{"_count":"desc"}}},"resolutions_selected":{"terms":{"field":"resolution","include":"FALSE-POSITIVE|WONTFIX|FIXED|REMOVED"}},"resolutions_missing":{"missing":{"field":"resolution"}}}}}}}}' on indices '[issues]' on types '[issue]'
    at org.sonar.server.es.request.ProxySearchRequestBuilder.get(ProxySearchRequestBuilder.java:49) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.es.request.ProxySearchRequestBuilder.get(ProxySearchRequestBuilder.java:37) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.issue.index.IssueIndex.search(IssueIndex.java:191) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.issue.IssueService.search(IssueService.java:351) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.issue.ws.SearchAction.execute(SearchAction.java:304) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.issue.ws.SearchAction.handle(SearchAction.java:279) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor169.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

Thanks,

Ravivarman.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the content of the `$SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es` folder and restarting your SonarQube server should fix the issue.